# Signalr .Net Client Console application receive messages from hub only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client, signalr.net-client

I'm using Signalr .Net Client in my Console application to receive messages from the Signalr Hub which is a separate web application.

My console application is connecting to the hub correctly and receive message from the hub only **once**. Then the client method in the Signalr .Net client not getting called.

Once I stop the console application and run it, again it receive a message from the hub only once and nothing happens.

Here is my **Hub Code**

```
public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            try
            {
                 var cType = Context.QueryString["type"];
                var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
                var connectedUserList = (from d in Users
                                         where d.ClientType == cType
                                                          select d).ToList();
                if (connectedUserList.Count > 0)
                {
                    var conUser = connectedUserList.First<ConnectedUsers>();
                    conUser.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
                }
                else
                {
                    var newUser = new ConnectedUsers
                    {
                        ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string> {connectionId}
                       ,
                        ClientType = cType
                    };
                    Users.Add(newUser);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

           ).Error(ex);
            }
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
```

And My .Net Client Connection

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SignalrHandler();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static async void SignalrHandler()
        {
            var url = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Url"] ?? @"http://localhost:1010/";
            var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "type", "WIN" } };
            _hubConnection = new HubConnection(url, querystringData);
            MarcolinMainProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MainHub");
            MarcolinMainProxy.On<string>("sendAlert", type => InvokeMethod(type));    
           await _hubConnection.Start();

        }
```

Client Method

```
private static void InvokeMethod(string type)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Recieved Message From Server On :{0}",System.DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine("Message Received");

            Console.ReadLine();


        }
```

And This happens when I use an Invoke method with following line

```
MarcolinMainProxy.On<string>("sendAlert", type => InvokeMethod(type));
```

And when I use following line it works..

```
MarcolinMainProxy.On<string>("sendAlert", stock => Console.WriteLine("Symbol {0} Price {1}", "sd", "sdde"));
```

Comment: Put a debug message after the call for `SignalrHandler` method to see if the execution of code passes it, maybe it doesn't block and keeps waiting for new messages, so the code listen the first time and after that the application ends

Comment: @HaithamShaddad I've updated the question. I think the problem is with the client invoke method.

Comment: So, it works when you keep the code inline but doesn't work if you called the `InvokeMethod` method?

Comment: Yes. It works when I use inline code

Comment: Try: `MarcolinMainProxy.On<string>("sendAlert", type => {InvokeMethod(type);});`

Comment: I tried.. But still have the issue.

Comment: Have a look at this link, basically, you can pass the method name directly without the lamda expression, ex:
`MarcolinMainProxy.On<string>("sendAlert", InvokeMethod);
`

https://damienbod.com/2013/11/13/signalr-messaging-a-complete-client-with-a-console-application/

Comment: I followed the link and changed my code and it worked. Thanks it really helped. Post It as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link

https://damienbod.com/2013/11/13/signalr-messaging-a-complete-client-with-a-console-application/

You have to change your code to

```
MarcolinMainProxy.On<string>("sendAlert", InvokeMethod);
```